Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets. If $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$, then $A\subseteq{B}$
I am currently learning proof writing. This is an example from book of proof on page 162. I have a different proof from the author's. But I wonder if it's correct. Besides, I have some doubts about the author's proof.
Here's my proof:

for $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$, then for every set $X\in{\mathcal{P}(A)}$, there is $X\in{\mathcal{P}(B)}$
for $X\in\mathcal{P}(A) \leftrightarrow X\subseteq{A}$. So $\forall x\in{X}, x\in{A}$
for $X\in\mathcal{P}(B) \leftrightarrow X\subseteq{B}$. So $\forall x\in{X}, x\in{B}$
for $\forall x\in{A}, x\in{B}$, so $A\subseteq{B}$

Here's the author's proof:

To show $A\subseteq{B}$,suppose that $a\in{A}$.
Then the one-element set $a$ is a subset of $A$, so $\{a\}\in\mathcal{P}(A)$.
But then, since $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$, it follows that $\{a\}\in\mathcal{P}(B)$.
This means that $\{a\}\subseteq{B}$,hence $a\in{B}$.
We’ve shown that $a\in{A}$ implies $a\in{B}$, so therefore $A\subseteq{B}$.

His proof is a lot different from mine. I wonder if it's rigorous to only construct a one-element set to prove the theorem.
Besides, I feel like some part of my proof is not so rigorous. Can you give me some advice on how to improve the proof?

The author's proof is both rigorous and correct. Your proof lacks justification for 3. implies 4. Actually, your 1.-3. are just statements of definitions. You have not really proved anything.

Alternatively, you may mention that, in particular, $A\in\mathcal P (A)$ and pick $X=A$.

The author proof is correct because $\mathcal{P}(A)$ contains all the subsets of $A$, so it includes every singleton sets.
For your proof, I prefer you add more explanation on the last step, because on the first three steps, you did not mention you are picking any elements from $A$, but only from a dummy set $X$. Most likely (if you want to use your idea), you need to add something like $$x\in A\text{, there exists }X\subseteq A\text{ such that }x\in X$$then apply all the stuffs you discussed in $1$ to $3$. And also $\leftrightarrow$ means bijection instead of logically equivalent ($\iff$).
